# Can't import python module from a subdirectory with a simple import statement

Tags: python

So I want to import a module from a python package that is a subdirectory of the one where the main script is located. This is the directory structure:

```
maindir \
  - main.py
  - modules \
    - __init__.py
    - module.py
```

What I find weird is that I can't import `module.py` with a simple `import modules.module`, because when I then try to call the function `module.foo()` in `main.py` it returns `NameError: name 'module' is not defined`. However, when I do `import modules.module as module`, everything works fine, the same with `from modules import module`. And when `module.py` is located in the same directory as `main.py`, a simple `import module` is completely sufficient for calling `module.foo()`.

Now the question is, why is that? Why isn't a simple `import` statement enough for importing a module from a package instead of the directory the script is in? Or am I doing something else wrong? An answer would be really appreciated since I am rather confused right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does import the module, it just doesn't make its name directly accessible.  When you do `import foo.bar`, the name that is imported is `foo`, and `bar` is only accessible as an attribute of that.  You use that form of import if that is what you want; that's what it's for.  If you don't want that, use a different form of the import statement.

If you want to be able to type `module` instead of `modules.module`, either do `import modules.module as module`, as you found, or do `from modules import module`.

Comment: The latter is the preferred method. The form containing the `as` keyword is primarily for importing and renaming the module in one line. e.g. `import somemodule as mymodule`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it might be something like this. I guess because I mainly coded in Java so far I'm used to not having to specify the full path to something after it has been imported...

Comment: @Cakejoke: You *don't* have to specify the full path, if you import it in the right way.  There are different forms of the import statement to let you choose which way you want to refer to the imported items.

Comment: True, but again, being from a Java environment I'm used to a simpler importing syntax. Still, that probably makes Python a little bit more flexible when dealing with multiple modules of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

When you import you still need to use the full package syntax to use the function foo.

The below should work

```
import modules.module
modules.module.foo()
```

A better way to do this is

```
from modules import module
module.foo()
```

A third less elegant way (but exactly the same as the above) is:

```
import modules.module as module
module.foo()
```